# How to add an exception a route for routing - laravel

Tags: wordpress, laravel, .htaccess

I'm using laravel.my server is centOS7 and apache2.

This is my routing:

```
http://example.com/{en}/{county}
```

But now I want to launch a blog page with url:

```
http://example.com/{en}/blog
```

how to add an expected url?

my blog is a wordpress.

Comment: have you tried to change the order of routes?

Comment: I think change order is incorrect. because I want to install a wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel parses the routes in the order they have been added. Try this order when registering the rotues.

[http://example.com/{en}/blog](http://example.com/%7Ben%7D/blog)

[http://example.com/{en}/{county}](http://example.com/%7Ben%7D/%7Bcounty%7D)

It will first match the blog and then move for the patterns.

Now if you run `php artisan route:list` you will see both the routes have been registered.

Comment: I think using http://example.com/{en}/blog is incorrect. because I want to install a wordpress site.

Comment: Are you trying to install a WordPress app inside a laravel project?

Answer (score 0):

by changing the order priority of routes will be changed...

try to use this order in the routes file `web.php`

```
.
.
http://example.com/{en}/blog
.
.
.
http://example.com/{en}/{county}
```

after that, you can redirect to your WordPress site URL:

```
Route::redirect('/{en}/blog', '/worpress-blog');
```

Comment: redirect is not a appropriate method.